# Clearing floats on the same line

Tags: css

I'm learning about floats at the moment, and I have a question.

Looking at the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pe0sL19x/2/), I am wondering if I can make it so that the background-color property only applies to the paragraph, and not the image.

I have tried putting `clear: both` inside the p's declaration, however, this makes the paragraph goes under the image, which is not what I wanted.

```css
body{
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.wrapper{
    max-width: 960px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

img{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}

p{
    background-color: rgb(0,200,255);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpapercave.com%2Fwp%2FTvGvWdR.jpg&f=1" />
        <p>Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium
        aenean. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo
        ullamcorper a lacus. Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Fringilla
        urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id leo in vitae turpis massa sed. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras
        adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque
        penatibus et magnis. Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Tortor
        posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras
        fermentum. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

All suggestions are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey there! My desired output, as stated in the description, is that I wanted the paragraph's background-color to stay without applying it to the image.

Comment: don't use floats - they shouldn't be used for layout in the day and age of css3 - either learn flex or css grid instead.  Also when asking a question - links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question itself, please don't ignore the rules of SO

Comment: _“which is not what I wanted”_ - “clearing floats” is not what you want to begin with here, that phrase has a different meaning.

Comment: Hey Pete! I'm currently learning about floats right now, and I'm experimenting with it. And also, about the rule, I didn't know it exists, I'm quite new here. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: _“if I can make it so that the background-color property only applies to the paragraph”_ - it already _does_. The paragraph itself is not what is floating around the image, the paragraph goes over the full width, even underneath the image. Only the _inline_ content of the paragraph floats around the image.

Comment: @misorude I didn't realize that until Simsteve7 told me about it. Thanks for extra information though, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the background-color of the image

```
background-color: #ffffff
```

And if you want that the margin is also white, you could use a border instead of margin.

```
border: 20px solid #ffffff
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, that definitely works, however, are there any more alternative ways to do this? I don't feel like overriding is the only way to go about it, but if there are no other ways to do, I'll accept this answer gladly.

Comment: By floating it, you could say that the image inlines with the `p`. So it's normal that it gets that bg color. 
If you hover over the <p> in your browsers  code inspector, you'll see that the <p> takes up the full width. That's also the reason why it keeps the padding left of the image, and not left of the text.

Comment: What you also could try, is to mark your text. Add a `span` around the text within the  `p`, and give the `span` a background-color.

Comment: This clears out a lot of things. Thank you for the explanation @Simsteve7, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpapercave.com%2Fwp%2FTvGvWdR.jpg&f=1" />
        <p>Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium
        aenean. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo
        ullamcorper a lacus. Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Fringilla
        urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id leo in vitae turpis massa sed. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras
        adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque
        penatibus et magnis. Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Tortor
        posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras
        fermentum. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.wrapper{
    max-width: 960px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;

    background-color: #ffffff;
}

img{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}

p{
    background-color: rgb(0,200,255);
    padding: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hey there! As stated in the description, I have done that before. What it did was lower my paragraph tag, which is not what I want. Thanks for the suggestion though! I appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another wrapper `div` around `p` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpapercave.com%2Fwp%2FTvGvWdR.jpg&f=1" />
        <div class="clear">
            <p>Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium
    aenean. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo
    ullamcorper a lacus. Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Fringilla
    urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id leo in vitae turpis massa sed. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras
    adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque
    penatibus et magnis. Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Tortor
    posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras
    fermentum. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the suggestion, however, this just move the background still applies to the image, it's just that there's a padding around paragraph. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Just added a new `clear` class to the div. Not sure if this fixes the padding issue